# Alexa widget shortcut iconography

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I see the new widget shortcut paradigm live on my Echo Show 8 II (though not yet on my Show 10"). My live custom skills are showing the default shortcut icon based on the category (smart home). The online docs at https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-haus/widget-guidelines do specify the requirements for a custom icon to represent the skill, but do not address where/how in the widget manifest the icon should be added/specified.

Does anybody know how to add a custom icon specification to the widget manifest?